# User Access Review custom report in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a way I can fetch all users currently assigned permissions to each resource created under a subscription.

To put in other words, I want to traverse all the resources created under a subscription & get the list of all users, service principal names, SGs, AAD groups, along with their role who have access to each resource. This report would help me perform a periodic user access review .

Any leads/code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply get that with the powershell command [`Get-AzRoleAssignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.Resources/Get-azRoleAssignment?view=azps-5.8.0).

Without any parameter, `Get-AzRoleAssignment` will get all the role assignments in the subscription, you can also leverage different parameters e.g. `-ObjectId`, `-Scope` to list assignments to a specific user/service principal/security group, or to list assignments on a specific resource group or resource.

For more details, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-powershell

Same thing also can be achieved by the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-rest), [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-cli), and SDK of different languages.

Comment: thanks, this helps but its missing the "Inherited" permissions. E.g. if I look at Storage Account permissions - this gives list of 'direct' assigned permissions but not the one's where scope is "Inherited" through Resource Group level or Subscription level. Any way we can list those as well ?